# Optimise query to avoid using temporary tables

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I'm stuck for 2 days with a simple query that I'm not able to optimise...
My table contains about 60,000,000 rows :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages_objects_likes` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `pages_objects_likes_page_id_created_time_index` (`page_id`,`created_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

My query is :

```
SELECT c.user_id, c.page_id,
COUNT(*) AS total
FROM pages_objects_likes c
WHERE page_id IN (116001391818501,37823307325,45502366281,30166294332,7133374462,223343965320,9654313055,123096413226,231809706871226,246637838754023,120063638018636)
AND created_time >= DATE_SUB('2014-06-30', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND created_time < DATE_SUB('2014-06-30', INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY c.user_id, c.page_id
```

But when I `EXPLAIN` it, I get this :

```
Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

I would like to optimise indexes or query because it is taking ages to execute (more than 5 minutes).
My server has SSD's, 32Gb or RAM and a 4 Core i5 dedicated to MySQL, so it is not a hardware issue :)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: How many rows does it have to scan (what is the total count). Also post the `EXPLAIN` output too.

Comment: And what do you have indexes on?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen the table schema is there...

Comment: edit: Ahh - misread :) Would try adding user_id to your index

Comment: I already tried, with no luck :(

Comment: What's your `innodb_buffer_pool_size`? with 32GB of ram you should be able to set it to 20GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution !

Update the index like this :

```
KEY `pages_objects_likes_page_id_created_time_index` (`page_id`,`user_id`,`created_time`)
```

And update the query by inverting the group by statement :

```
GROUP BY c.page_id, c.user_id
```

The index is now used everywhere ;)

Answer (score -1):

I would guess your problem is with DATE_SUB functions, in general using functions in WHERE is a bad Idea because

1. They evaluate each and every record in your tables.
2. DB Engines skip indexes usually when the fields are passed to functions.

My suggestion is to pass the DATE_SUB output from client side, or to calculate it once before the start of the query.

I also might be tempted to put an index on "created_time", "page_id", "user_id" and see how it goes.

Comment: This is just wrong... in this case it will not be called for each row and indexes can be used. Also, an index with created_time first cannot use the 2-nd part because of the range condition.

Comment: @Vatev depends on the decisions of the optimizer, either it will evaluate the IN first or the created_time first. And regarding the index, I said "in general" not this specific case, I hope u read carefully before commenting or voting.

Comment: It cannot use any part of an index after a range condition. If you have a `created_time,page_id` index and a `created_time between const and const` condition (or equivalent) it cannot use page_id from that index for filtering. `page_id,created_time` in this case is the correct index and the best possible for that where condition.